# A block created with Views is not rendered if the page URL contains "page="

Tags: 7, views, paging, theming

I have an odd problem. I'm using Drupal 7 and an Omega subtheme. Within Views, I have a block defined and it works great - appears where it's supposed to all over the site - except when the URL has a "?page=" in it. Some possibly relevant info: clean_urls and pathauto enabled, Delta and Layout installed but no Deltas defined.

I discovered this when I created a page View (of a different content-type) that features the pager to scroll through the results. When using the pager it appends "?page=1", "?page=2", etc to the URL. I think it does it by default and from what I've read it seems to be difficult to change this. I could probably put up with the non-clean URLs but the bigger issue now is trying to work out why this results in my first view block not being rendered. I've tested it out by navigating to random pages on the site and appending the "?page=" to the URl and it's always the same result - the block view's not displayed.

Do you have any idea, or any pointer to where I should start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I worked out what the problem was. The way the View selected the content, there could only be one result (the View is to show the current exhibition for an art gallery website, and they only ever have one exhibition at once). Because by design it could only produce one result I didn't even think about the pager, which was to Full by default.

This caused problems when that block was rendered on the same page as another View - one which deliberately has a pager. Maybe there's an issue with multiple pagers on the same webpage?

Anyway, I changed the block View's pager settings to "Display a specified number of items | 1 item" and that fixed everything - now there's only ever one pager on the webpage and now my block view is displayed on every page as it's supposed to.

Edit: Will click this as accepted answer in 2 days when I'm allowed to